# How can i detect a click event on the alert presented in foreground when a push notification received?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

currently i am able to display an alert in the foreground , but i want a click event on the notification alert so i redirect to some other screen. here is the code snippet.

```
if (isDomainVerification)
{
    NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc postNotificationName:@"domainverificationNotification" object:self userInfo:data];
}
else if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"data"]) {
    data = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"message"];
    isDeactivated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectForKey:@"is_deactivated"]];
    if ([isDeactivated isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [self updateFamilyAlertDeactivation:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectForKey:@"emergency_state"]] andMarkerId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectForKey:@"marker_id"]] deactData:data];
    }
    else{
        [self saveReceiveAlert:[userInfo objectForKey:@"data"]];
        if (isSafetyMember) {

            ****completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);****


        }
        else{
            [self display_notification:[userInfo objectForKey:@"data"]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add alert code.